# When I call df on pandas, rows are being repeated over and over

Tags: python, pandas

I've checked and up to the point of for loop its correct and then whenever I call df it becomes 800 rows. There are only 100 rows in the table that I'm pulling data through. I don't know where or what's causing the issue.

Page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_in_the_United_States_by_revenue#cite_note-2

```
table1 = soup.find_all('table')[1]
print(table1)

table1_headers = table1.find_all('th')
print(table1_headers)

processed_t1h = [t1h_data.text.strip() for t1h_data in table1_headers]
processed_t1h

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = processed_t1h)
df

column_data = table1.find_all('tr')
column_data

for row in column_data[1:]:
    row_data = row.find_all('td')
    individual_row_data = [data.text.strip() for data in row_data]
    print(individual_row_data)
    
    length = len(df)
    finaldata = df.loc[length] = individual_row_data
    print(finaldata)

df
```

[image: For Loop shows 100 rows]

[image: df shows 800 rows]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you were trying to do in:

```
finaldata = df.loc[length] = individual_row_data
```

Instead, at the top of your code initiate finaldata:

```
finaldata = pd.DataFrame()
```

And instead of the above line of code use concat:

```
finaldata = pd.concat([finaldata,individual_row_data])
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks man! I did not know what even happened. I just replaced the df with finaldata and its now okay. I did not even do the concat.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work...I've checked and it returns a dataframe of 100 rows

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'url'
response = requests.get(url)
html_content = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
table1 = soup.find_all("table")[1]
table1_headers = table1.find_all('th')
processed_t1h = [t1h_data.text.strip() for t1h_data in table1_headers]
processed_t1h
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = processed_t1h)
df
column_data = table1.find_all('tr')
column_data
for row in column_data[1:]:
    row_data = row.find_all('td')
    individual_row_data = [data.text.strip() for data in row_data]
    length = len(df)
    finaldata = df.loc[length] = individual_row_data
    print(finaldata)
df
```

Comment: thanks for the answer man. Was able to fix it. I think it has got something to do with logical error on initiating the dataframe. I just reviewed, re-initiate and change the variable name of the dataframe and it somehow worked.